# How to get value from bs4 resultset in beautifulsoap?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all title value from this bs4 resultset?

```
[<span class="zaman" title="16.3.2022 15:22:44">1 hf.</span>, <span class="hide zaman pull-right ml-5 mt--1">( Mesaj Silindi )</span>,<span class="zaman" title="16.3.2022 15:32:01">1 hf.</span>, <span class="hide zaman pull-right ml-5 mt--1">( Mesaj Silindi )</span>]
```

How can I get all value of title  like 16.3.2022 15:22:44 , 16.3.2022 15:32:01 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the digits value as follows:

```
html='''
<span class="zaman" title="16.3.2022 15:22:44">
 1 hf.
</span>
,
<span class="hide zaman pull-right ml-5 mt--1">
 ( Mesaj Silindi )
</span>
,
<span class="zaman" title="16.3.2022 15:32:01">
 1 hf.
</span>
,
<span class="hide zaman pull-right ml-5 mt--1">
 ( Mesaj Silindi )
</span>

'''

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup= BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())
    
    value = [x.get('title') for x in soup.find_all('span', class_="zaman")]
    value=value[0]+ ' , ' + value[2]
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
16.3.2022 15:22:44 , 16.3.2022 15:32:01
```